# SMTPSendFailedException if send from server andd all work if send from local computer

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail

When I sent email from my computer - all work fine but when I try from server I get error:

```
2018-02-05 15:37:06.233  INFO 2692 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] r.m.s.n.services.impl.E
mailServiceImpl   : Sending Email with Freemarker HTML Template
2018-02-05 15:37:06.733 ERROR 2692 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] r.m.s.n.c.common.Except
ionHandlerAdvice  : Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:
555 5.5.2 Syntax error. p70sm1785955lja.62 - gsmtp
```

My code:

```
@Override
  public void sendSimpleMessage(MailRequest mailRequest) {
    log.info("Sending Email with Freemarker HTML Template");
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    try {
      helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      helper.setTo(mailRequest.getUserEmailAddress());
      helper.setText("test", true);
      helper.setSubject("test");
      emailSender.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new EmailSendException(e);
    }
  }
```

I try start my jar on server with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` (because message was contains UTF-8 chars) - not helped

I remove all UTF-8 chars and replase it by "test" - not helped

config:

```
#mail
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=myemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: @DaImTo I add code to question